# keyword printing with achemso template

Tags: keywords, achemso

I am using 'achemso' package template on MixTex 2.9 and trying to print my keywords, but could not succeed. I have read that there is a bug fix report on the 'change history' section of the achemso document for keyword printing, however, could not figure out how to utilize that. Could you please help me on that? Thank you.

Comment: To print keywords, please add \setkeys{acs}{keywords = true} after the \documentclass..line.

Comment: ;-), got it @Johannes_B

Answer (score 3):

I have solved the problem with support of previous answers. For anyone needed; To print keywords, please add `\setkeys{acs}{keywords = true}` after the `\documentclass` line.